# What causes "Screen Sharing cannot be opened because of a problem"?

Tags: high-sierra, screen-sharing

When I attempt to start the Screen Sharing application (`/Applications/Screen Sharing.app`) on my macOS 10.13.6 MacBook Pro 2017, I get the error "Screen Sharing cannot be started because of a problem". Googling around, I can't find any discussion about this. I've used Screen Sharing in the past without trouble. I've rebooted and my system is up to date with the latest software as of today. Networking is turned on, I'm connected to a network, I'm not out of disk space, and have no other obvious problems with my system.

What can cause this problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: when you get cryptic error like that `"Screen Sharing cannot be started because of a problem"`, Apple does not know what caused it, otherwise it will tell you.

Comment: However you can do some research your self. Open Console app in Utility folder. Now watch it what does it do from exactly the time stamp when you enable Screen Sharing. If you want help with it, copy/paste some 30 lines here from the time stamp of activation.